# Why do I get a Some instead of a String in Scala

Tags: scala

Why do I get a [Some] Object instead of a [String] Object?
The Some object won't work as a String Parameter in a method call.

The `config def` returns a `String` so I expect the type to be `String`.
 But when I type "Hello" Scala get's it correct.

Code

```
    def config(s: String) = Play.current.configuration.getString(s).toString()
    Logger.info(config("recaptcha.publicKey"))
    Logger.info("Hello")
```

Output

```
[info] application - Some(6LeDMdASAAAAAC4CFIDY-5M7NEZ_WnO0NO9CSdtj)
[info] application - Hello
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are unnecessarily calling `toString()` on `Option[String]` (which `Play.current.configuration.getString()` returns), try this:

```
def config(s: String) = Play.current.configuration.getString(s).get
```

or <del>maybe</del> preferably:

```
Play.current.configuration.getString(s).getOrElse("some default")
```

Comment: @Luigi +1 for the info. But I get the feeling you are being sarcastic. I prefer a RuntimeException... fail hard, fast and at the correct place in the stack trace rather than later at a random place. If my configuration file is miss typed I want to know it pronto with a bang.

Comment: @Farmor fair enough, but if you actually want it to throw an Exception, you still shouldn't use `get`: use `getOrElse(sys.error("Illegal config String"))` to separate concerns, clarify the error message, and make it more explicit that you're actually doing a validity check here.

Comment: Thanks, that makes great sense

Answer (score 11):

getString returns an Option[String], so that it can return an empty value when there is nothing to return. When there is something to return, it returns Some(string) and you can get the inner string using the get() method.